# Unable to add mention tag(@ tag ) with my fb feed through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to mention tag users/pages(i.e like tagging using @ symbol normaly in facebook) in my feed. I have tried the following Graph API,

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/feed
```

with following parameter,

```
  message = "My message @[<user_id>:1:<username>]"
```

I tried this from graph API explorer, feed is getting posted but the people/page which am tagging is not working, It is not coming as a link it is coming as a plain text.

I want to post a feed like shown in the image i attached, how can I achieve it need help,

[image]

Comment: You can not tag users in normal posts made via API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the documentation. You should use the Taggable Friends API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed/#publish

You should fill the `tags` parameter of your post.

Comment: I want to do a mention tag i.e like using @<username> @<pagename> is this possible?

Comment: No, there is a special API for that, as I outlined.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the original question which was about inline mentions, not separate tags.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @Tobi's answer. Here's a complete example on how to publish a post and tagging friends:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test message",
        "place": "link",
        "tags": "friend_id1,friend_id2"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response); /* post id will be returned */
      }
    }
);
```